# Win32: Control support insert and append text control?

Tags: c++, winapi, append, controls

[image]

I wrote a c# WPF app contain a textblock that I can insert Run controls to it. Now I'm writing a same Win32 application. Problem is i'm new to Win32, so I dont know if there is a control that:

- Can append text-like controls
- Support text-wrap or auto break
- **Each text control I add to support left and right click event for further action.**

I'm considering Static text control add to dialog but it don't support append next to existing control.
So, I ask is there any control can fit my need? Thank!
*(Below is code I use to show above popup, in which I append Run controls to TextBlock)*

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" KeyUp="tb_KeyUp" TextChanged="tb_TextChanged" BorderThickness="0" TabIndex="1" IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled="True" UndoLimit="1000" Padding="4,0,0,0" Background="Yellow" AcceptsReturn="True"/>
    <Popup Name="tip" VerticalOffset="3" HorizontalOffset="-1" Opened="tip_Opened" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" PopupAnimation="Scroll">
        <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="White">
            <ScrollViewer MaxHeight="700" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <Grid>
                    <ListView x:Name="lb" Focusable="False" SelectionMode="Single" BorderThickness="0" MouseUp="lb_MouseUp"/>
                    <DockPanel Name="d_tbl" Visibility="Collapsed">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="21" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                            <ComboBox/>
                            <ComboBox/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Name="tbl" FontSize="16" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Padding="10" MaxWidth="800" TextWrapping="Wrap" MouseUp="tbl_MouseUp"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```